# Error trying to save vectorfile in QGIS 2.10?

Tags: qgis, vector, error

I'm trying to save some changes I made in a vector file (polygons) in QGIS 2.10.

The file contains properties and I want to merge two of them into one.
I toggled and selected the two and then pressed [image]

But when I try to save my changes, I get an error message that says that it could not be saved. 
Export to vectorlayer failed. Object geometry not imported. OGR-error. 
This is my translation of the original message (Swedish).

It worked the first time I merged two properties and saved, but not when I try to do the same thing again?

QGIS doesn't crash, I just can't save my work.

I use Windows 8.

Comment: After merging, have you tried saving it as a **new** shapefile using the _Save As..._ option?

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but I still get the error message.

Comment: Perhaps save the shapefile (before trying to merge) as a new shapefile and see if you can merge features for this shapefile instead?

Comment: Did you try to check permissions to QGIS folder ? Lets try to give a full access to QGIS installation folder and to the path where you save .shp files.